# Nested for loop in perl

Tags: perl, loops, nested

I'm trying to make a little script with a nested "for" loop in perl.
As I'm learning, at first I've done 3 for loops and it worked well. In order to make something more intelligent, I'd like to nested them but I don't know what is wrong.

If my input text is ABCDEFGHI
I'd like to obtain

```
text 1 ABC DEF GHI
text 2 BCD EFG HI
text 3 CDE FGH I
```

But instead of it, my output is

```
text1 ABC DEF GHI ABC DEF GHI ABC DEF GHI ABC DEF GHI ABC DEF GHI ABC DEF GHI ABC DEF GHI ABC DEF GHI ABC DEF GHI
text2 BCD EFG HI BCD EFG HI BCD EFG HI
text3 CDE FGH I
```

Here is my script. I'm using perl 5.18.1.

```
use Modern::Perl '2013';

my @text1;
my @text2;
my @text3;

my $entry = shift;
my $len = length $entry;

for (my $i = 2; $i < $len; $i += 3) {
    for (my $i = 1; $i < $len; $i += 3) {
        for (my $i = 0; $i < $len; $i += 3) {
            my $text = substr($entry, $i, 3);
            push @text1, uc($text);
        }
        my $text = substr($entry, $i, 3);
        push @text2, uc($text);
    }
    my $text = substr($entry, $i, 3);
    push @text3, uc($text);
}

say "text1 @text1";
say "text2 @text2";
say "text3 @text3";
```

I've already taken a look around and here http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops

Thank you for any help

Comment: I'm assuming you're just trying to learn more? If that's the case you should know that nested for loops are something you should try to avoid if possible, they only make your programs run much slower. It's possible to do what you're trying to do with just one loop.

Comment: What makes you think that the inner loop should nor execute 27 times?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to learn more. I thought 3 independent loops was not very intelligent. So, thank you for your advice!

Comment: @Arkadiy Everytime the more outer loop starts, the inners loops re-starts... but can't figure out what to do.

Comment: @Tetraodienne "Not very intelligent" isn't really the criterion you want to be using here; rather, "gets the job done" will serve you much better. (Nested loops are also to be avoided in general, where possible, because of their complexity cost. Consider an outer loop which runs ten times, and an inner loop which runs ten times; the process as a whole has to go through 100 iterations to complete the outer loop. Now consider an outer loop which runs ten times, and an inner loop which runs *ten thousand* times...)

Comment: @Aaron Miller, `/a.*b/` (being short for `/^.*?a.*b/`) has two nested loops, yet you wouldn't have paused if you had seem that. You use them when you have to use them.

Comment: @ikegami Of course you do. My point is that, where you *don't* have to use them, you're better off not to. For someone who is just starting to feel his way into the concept, that seems to me like something it'd be helpful to point out, so I did.

Comment: it's generally bad form to use the same index variable in nested loops -- if you use `$i, $j, $k`, rather than recycling `$i`, you'll run into fewer problems when you have to come back later.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you'd want three nested loops (not counting `substr`). You only need two: One loop to determine the starting position, and one to walk through the string.

```
my $text = uc('ABCDEFGHI');
for my $offset (0..2) {
   my @parts;
   for (my $i=$offset; $i<length($text); $i+=3) {
      push @parts, substr($work, $i, 3);
   }

   say "@parts";
}
```

Or without `substr`. to truly demonstrate there are really only two loops:

```
my $text = uc('ABCDEFGHI');
my @text = split //, $text;
for my $offset (0..2) {
   my @parts;
   for my $i ($offset..$#text) {
      $parts[ ($i - $offset) / 3 ] .= $text[$i];
   }

   say "@parts";
}
```

Personally, I'd use

```
my $text = uc('ABCDEFGHI');
for (1..3) {
   my @parts = $text =~ /\G.{1,3}/sg;
   say "@parts";

   $text =~ s/^.//s;
}
```

Comment: I guess it is a matter of personal preferences when using `print(..)`?  It is very uncommon for perl.

Comment: @mpapec, As oppose to what?

Comment: `print ""` is more common than `print("")`

Comment: @mpapec, You can omit parens from sub and function calls, but it's dangerous. For example, `print(($x+$y)/2)` is not the same as `print ($x+$y)/2`.

Comment: Not when using warnings? `perl -we 'print (3+3)/2'`

Comment: @mpapec, Even with warnings on, though you do get a warning for that example, yes.

Comment: Ok, do you use parens only for educational purposes, or in all circumstances? I'm using them sparsely.

Comment: @Tetraodienne, I had misread what your code did (add spaces vs split into bits). Changed my code to be more like yours. The reasoning hasn't changed.

Comment: @ikegami I was just studying your code and also realised that your proposition didn't split it! :-) would love to be comfy with regex!

Comment: @Tetraodienne, I've just added a little more to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your three loops do not need to be nested to get your desired output:

```
use Modern::Perl '2013';

my @text1;
my @text2;
my @text3;

my $entry = shift;
my $len = length $entry;

for (my $i = 0; $i < $len; $i += 3) {
   my $text = substr($entry, $i, 3);
   push @text1, uc($text);
}

for (my $i = 1; $i < $len; $i += 3) {
   my $text = substr($entry, $i, 3);
   push @text2, uc($text);
}

for (my $i = 2; $i < $len; $i += 3) {        
    my $text = substr($entry, $i, 3);
    push @text3, uc($text);
}

say "text1 @text1";
say "text2 @text2";
say "text3 @text3";
```

You *could* also re-factor this a little, using two nested loops:

```
use Modern::Perl '2013';

my @texts = ( [], [], [] );

my $entry = shift;
my $len = length $entry;

for ( my $start = 0; $start < 3; $start++ ) {
  for ( my $i = $start; $i < $len; $i += 3 ) {
     my $text = substr($entry, $i, 3);
     push @{$texts[$start]}, uc($text);
  }
}

for ( my $start = 0; $start < 3; $start++ ) {
  say "text${start} @{$texts[$start]}";
}
```

As an aside: If you do nest `for` loops, it will be easier to read and understand your code if you use a different variable as the iterator. The three `$i` variables you have will work, but I had to check quite a while to make sure that wasn't your problem.